# SonarQube: Is something like a "settings profile" possible/planned for sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

We share a SonarQube 6.2 istance between some teams. Every team uses their own quality profiles and gates for their different projects.
Now we'd like something similiar for the settings. We don't want to set analysis scope and such for the SQ instance because they differ between teams. On the other hand a teams doesn't want to maintain the same settings for a number of projects.
Is it planned to provide a "Settings Profile" to share between projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing settings between projects will be possible at some point of time on our [online SonarQube.com service](https://sonarqube.com/) thanks to the concept of organization that we will introduce very soon.

For SonarQube on premise installation, nothing is planned on that topic for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.